# QT Threading, order of signals

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, signals, slot

i can nowhere find an exact solutin for my problem.
I have the base class "main" with 6 instances of an object "psu". Each "psu" has an instance of an additional class "sender" witch sends messages over udp.
Each instance is using an extra port for sending the messages. Now the idea was, to make an instance of "sender" in the "main" class and put it on a new thread, using moveToThread. Now all six "psu instances should emit an signal when they want to send a message over udp. If they do it in a short time, do the signals go in a queue? Or will there be an manipulation of my data that i transmit via the signals?

I hope you understand what i mean and can give me an exact answer.

Do i need the Mutex things?

Short notice: I use an self defined struct witch represents the packet i send.

Best regards
MAX

Comment: If I understood right [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246933/order-of-slots-called-on-qobject) question should help you

Comment: It's not exactly the same thing i think... i send signals from many instances to one slot in another thread... not from one instance to the same instance... ot does qt handle this the same way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If multiple slots have a Qt::DirectConnection, they will be invoked in the order they were connected. If multiple slots have a Qt::QueueConnection, they will be invoked in the order they were connected. If you mix and match, then all Qt::DirectionConnection slots will invoke in order, then when control returns to event loop, all the Qt::QueuedConnection slots will invoke in order.
[Credit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31751605/in-qt-many-slots-connected-to-the-same-signal-do-they-invoke-in-order-when-emit)